# How to disable or remove kite from intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, kite

**Problem** 
I was curious about Kite in Intellij but after i tried it i didnt like it, but i couldnt disable it, Uninstall it or any way to remove the annoying suggestions.

I tried disabling it in
`Settings > Language and frameworks > Kite > and unchecked start kite at start up`
,
 I also Unchecked all the other options but it still giving suggestions 
I have Intellij Ultimate 2020.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the [Kite AI Code AutoComplete](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15148-kite-ai-code-autocomplete-python-java-javascript-html-css-go-c-c-c-) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by this:
Settings-> Plugins-> right click on Kite AI Code AutoComplete plugins -> Uninstall
then restart your IDE.
This work also for Android studio.